# mvc6 json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a custom JSON Guid serialisation/deserializationusing Asp.Net Core, but I'm unable to modify the default deserialization to add my code in.

I've got the serialisation down with this:
Startup.cs

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;   
 
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0, new GuidConverter());        
 
});
 }
```

But it seems this only applys to outbound messages, not inbound.

For reference, by converter code is this:

```
public class GuidConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType == typeof(Guid) || objectType == typeof(Guid?);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (null == value) {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        var nullableGuid = value as Guid?;

        Guid guid;
        if (nullableGuid.HasValue) {
            guid = nullableGuid.Value;
        } else {
            guid = (Guid)value;
        }

        writer.WriteValue(guid.ToShort());
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String) {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Unexpected token parsing Guid. Expected String, got {0}.", reader.TokenType));
        }

        var guid = GuidUtility.FromShort((string)reader.Value);

        return guid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should try **NewtonSoft** package for serialization and deserialization

Comment: I wish to compress the Guid to save space. So to do that I want to add a converter into the existing json serialisation (which  I believe uses NewtonSoft)